# Почему не запускается в android-studio проект с github и активити неактивные?

Tags: android-studio, github

Скачал проект архивом с github, распаковал, открыл в андроид студио. Кнопка запуска неактивна, активити и классы серенькие и с кружочком красным с восклицательным знаком. что надо сделать, чтобы проект запустился?[image: скрин из андроид студио]

Comment: скачал вот отсюда https://github.com/triggs/NLevelExpandableListView

Comment: Как вы импортировали проект в студию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный проект был создан в Eclipse. Чтобы его корректно открыть в андроид-студио, необходимо открывать через Import Project